Getting error when dowloading apple stock price from Yahoo
When I run my code to get stock data from yahoo it keeps returning me "no time zone found, symbol may be delisted".
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
today = date.today()

d1 = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

end_date = d1
d2 = date.today() - timedelta(days=720)
d2 = d2.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
start_date = d2

data = yf.download('AAPL',
start=start_date,
end=end_date,
progress=False)
print(data.head())

Failed to get ticker 'AAPL' reason: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='fc.yahoo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)')))

1 Failed download:
['AAPL']: Exception('%ticker%: No timezone found, symbol may be delisted')
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Open, High, Low, Close, Adj Close, Volume]
Index: []

